# Select record from table (and some conditions)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I don't want to use pure sql query but I can't deal with Active Records methods.

I have models like those:

```
class Car < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :reviews
end
```

and

```
class Review < AcriveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :cars
end
```

And now I want get all reviews for specific Car. You know I want to select all records from reviews where car_id is the same (just all reviews for specific car).

I'm trying with http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html but it still doesn't work.

Comment: so just call `reviews` on the car object, like `@car.reviews`

Comment: You should be careful with pluralization of objects in Ruby on Rails. Read it and see if it makes sense in English. It's something unusual but easier to read.

Comment: note about pluralization: specifically it's `belongs_to :car` not `belongs_to :cars`

Answer (score 2):

You will be able to get all reviews of a car by:

```
@car.reviews
```

Update your `review.rb` model as:

```
class Review < AcriveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :car # SINGULAR !
end
```

It will give you facility to fetch `car` for a `review` as:

```
@review.car
```

Comment: when I write `@car.reviews` in Car model I got from RSpec `undefined method 'reviews' for nil:NilClass`. Why?

Comment: `@car` is a variable and you need to assign a value to it like: `@car = Car.find(<car_id>)` then you can find `reviews` of that car as `@car.review`

Answer (score 1):

Just find the car object you want, something like this for example

```
@car = Car.find(id: params[id])
```

Then all associations are easily accessed by their names, wihout needing to do a query

```
@reviews = @car.reviews
```

Comment: Thank's, this was really helpful. And if I had in table REVIEWS column RATING and I would like to get all ratings for specific car? (rating is column in reviews table and I want eg. sum them of something else)

Comment: You could do things like `@car.reviews.count` to get total reviews count, or `@car.reviews.average(:rating)` to get the average rating for that object, also `@car.reviews.sum(:whatever)` works too

Answer (score 1):

This is very straightforward. First get the Active record for car with, say id stored in variable car_id

```
@car = Car.find(car_id)
@car.reviews #This will get you the reviews
```

To avoid multiple DB calls, u can use includes

```
@car = Car.includes(:reviews).find(car_id)
```

If you just want the reviews then

```
@reviews = Review.where(:car_id=>car_id) #provided car_id is the foreign key here
```